# Replace special character with white space through regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a function which replace character.

```
public static string Replace(string value)
{
    value = Regex.Replace(value, "[\n\r\t]", " ");
    return value;
}
```

```
value="abc\nbcd abcd    abcd\ "
```

if in string there is any unwanted white space they are also remove.Means I want result like this
`value="abcabcdabcd"`.
Help to change `Regex Pattern` to get desire result.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Too late to answer, but have a look at http://regexhero.net/tester/ - it has a silverlight UI which lets you experiment, and can give you the c# code when you're happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to remove any number of whitespace characters from the string, probably you're looking for something like this:

```
value = Regex.Replace(value, @"\s+", "");
```

where `\s` matches any whitespace character and `+` means one or more times.

Comment: I try it.its gives a result `abc bcd abcd abcd `.I want t0 remove all white space.It only replace `\n` not other whitespace.Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing your newline, tab, etc. characters with a space, just replace all whitespace with nothing:

```
public static string RemoveWhitespace(string value)
{
    return Regex.Replace(value, "\\s", "");
}
```

`\s` is a special character group that matches all whitespace characters. (The backslash is doubled because the backslash has a special meaning in C# strings as well.) The following MSDN link contains the exact definition of that character group:

- [Character Classes: White-Space Character: \s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WhitespaceCharacter)

Comment: @NeilMoss: By default, Regex.Replace replaces all occurrences. It's possible that either `\s` or `\s+` is more efficient, but that would need to be tested.

Comment: learn a little every day. Thanks. I'll drop that comment shortly.

Comment: @NeilMoss: You can also think about it this way: If Regex.Replace were to only replace the first occurrence, \s+ would fail on `"abc <more spaces> abc <more spaces> abc"`, because it would only remove the first sequence of spaces.

Comment: Just playing on regex hero with the sample input given above - it claims s+ is some 39% faster. I don't know how authorative that is, or even why. But now we know!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `\s` indicating white spaces. With the statement `Regex.Replace(value, @"\s", "")`, the output will be "abcabcdabcd".